# How to write 'global' inline functions in Objective-C (using C syntax)

Tags: objective-c, c, static, inline, extern

Assuming I'm including a header file in my precompiled header that includes a bunch of inline functions to be used as helpers wherever needed in any of the project's TUs -- what would be the correct way to write those inlines?

1) as static inlines? e.g.:

```
static inline BOOL doSomethingWith(Foo *bar)
{
   // ...
}
```

2) as extern inlines? e.g.:

in Shared.h

```
extern inline BOOL doSomethingWith(Foo *bar);
```

in Shared.m

```
inline BOOL doSomethingWith(Foo *bar)
{
   // ...
}
```

---

My intention with inlines is to:

- make the code less verbose by encapsulating common instructions
- to centralize the code they contain to aid with future maintenance
- to use them instead of macros for the sake of type safety
- to be able to have return values

So far I have only seen variant 1) in the wild.
I have read (sadly can't find it anymore) that variant 1) does not accurately move the inline function's body into the callers but rather creates a new function, and that only `extern inline` ensures that kind of behavior.

Comment: An additional reason why replacing macros with static inline functions is a good idea is this: When you have a multi-line macro, it is squashed down to a single line, and cannot be reasonably debugged, because the line information is messed up and the debugger cannot track progress through the macro. Inline functions don't do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> make the code less verbose by encapsulating common instructions

Non-inline functions do that as well...

> to centralize the code they contain to aid with future maintenance

then you should have non-`inline` functions, don't you think?

> to use them instead of macros for the sake of type safety
>
> to be able to have return values

those seem OK to me.

---

Well, when I write `inline` functions, I usually make them `static` - that's typically how it's done. (Else you can get all sorts of mysterious linker errors if you're not careful enough.) It's important to note that `inline` does **not** affect the visibility of a function, so if you want to use it in multiple files, you need the `static` modifier.

An `extern inline` function does not make a lot of sense. If you have only one implementation of the function, that defeats the purpose of inline. If you use link-time optimization (where cross-file inlining is done by the linker), then the `inline` hint *for the compiler* is not very useful anyway.

> only extern inline insures that kind of behavior.

It doesn't "ensure" anything at all. There's no portable way to force inlining - in fact, most modern compilers ignore the keyword completely and use heuristics instead to decide when to inline. In GNU C, you *can* force inlining using the `__attribute__((always_inline))` attribute, but unless you have a very good reason for that, you shouldn't be doing it.

Answer (score 7):

Skipping whether you should be inlining at all for the reasons you give, the standard way to inline in Cocoa is to use the predefined macro `NS_INLINE` - use it either in the source file using the function or in an imported header. So your example becomes:

```
NS_INLINE BOOL doSomethingWith(Foo *bar)
```

For GCC/Clang the macro uses `static` and the `always_inline` attribute.

Most (maybe all) compilers won't inline `extern inline` as they operate on a single compile unit at a time - a source file along with all its includes.